# SQL Server Management Studio Ignores Windows Proxy for connection

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, sqlconnection, cloud-sql-proxy, sql-server-2019

I'm using corporate VPN when connecting to Azure SQL Server DB.
When I'm trying to establish the connection using SQL Server Management Studio 2019, the 'Connect to server' dialogue is showing me that I'm trying to connect using my original Dynamic IP.
I have tried Netsh, and other tricks but was in vain, the SQL management studio insists on using my original IP.
so I have a couple of questions:

1. Why is this happening? Why SQL management studio is not using my proxy IP for TCP connection?
2. Could it be that the Azure SQL Server is using some mechanism to detect that I'm using proxy and force my connection to be established via my original IP?
3. What can I do to solve this issue? how can I force the SQL management studio to use my proxy IP for 
   TCP connection?

Comment: i have the exact same issue and SSMS never reaches the corporate proxy to resolve IP for an Azure SQL DB hostname.  Did you get this issue resolved ? how did you fix it?

Comment: Might be blocking you from corporate firewall. Ask your network admin to whitelist you from accessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be blocking you from corporate firewall. Ask your network admin to whitelist you from accessing. Hope this might help.

Comment: If it was firewall we would have gotten a different error like timed out or something.  Local pcaps indicate that SSMS nor any microsoft desktop tool doesnt even pick up the proxy settings on the workstation to reach corp proxy servers to resolve IP for Azure SQL Database.

Comment: Did you managed to resolve this issue. We also have the exact issue and even after trying different options it seems the request from MSMS or any other desktop clients is not reaching the proxy server.